# How can I install packages from yarn cache without using internet?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I happened to read from a book that yarn caches all installed packages so as to allow the developer to be able to install packages without internet connection. I tried it and it didn't work. Did I get the instructions wrong or I just misunderstood what I read?

*UPDATE*
I was able to figure it out. All I needed to do was to add the "offline" flag after writing the installation command. Example: To install axios,
`yarn add axios --offline`

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood, a package is cached only when you have already installed it.

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/